# JBoss AS 7 is also compatible with JavaEE5?

Tags: jboss7.x, java-ee-5

JBoss AS 7 is also compatible with JavaEE5 ? or I must use JavaEE 6?
I cann't find the document about the compatibiliy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for most practical reasons it is compatible. It does not mean that JBoss especially built support for older version, but Java EE 6 itself is more like superset of Java EE 5. As result you can deploy application that uses only features that were available in Java EE 5 to the application server that supports Java EE 6 features.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can run my application on JBoss 7 with JavaEE 5.